# Argument 1 passed to App\Mail\SurveyMail::__construct() must be an instance of App\Mail\User, array give

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to send emails to the users who have been accepted by the admin using mailable api in Laravel 5.3.

```
class SurveyMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user=$user;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('mail.send')
        ->from('monsite@chezmoi.com');
    }
```

and this is my controller

```
 class EmailController extends Controller
{
    public function send(Request $request,User $user)
    {    
         Mail::to($user)
         ->send(new SurveyMail ($request->except('_token')));
    }
}
```

the view:

```
<body style="background: black; color: white">
 <h2>Prise de contact sur mon beau site</h2>
    <p>Réception d'une prise de contact avec les éléments suivants :</p>
    <ul>

      <li><strong>Nom</strong> : {{ $user->name }}</li>
      <li><strong>Email</strong> : {{ $user->email }}</li>


</body>
```

it seems that the argument `User` which is passed to the constructor is not accepted. Please, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `SurveyMail` construct add `App\` or add `use App\User` on the top of it :

```
public function __construct(App\User $user)
{
    $this->user=$user;
}
```

And then the call should be like this :

```
Mail::to($user)
      ->send(new SurveyMail ($user));
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ,but the error persist even with this modification

Comment: yes,it works now perfectly thanks a lot , but why i have a lot of the same mail in my mailtrap box however i sent it one time.

Comment: try to remove all of them and try one more time

Comment: same thing after removing

Comment: Ok, how this `send` function is called ?

Comment: Route::get('/admin/{user}/send','EmailController@send')->name('user.send');

Comment: And you call this route from the view ?? one time ?

Comment: I think when ever the page is refreshed ,it send emails

Comment: @foreach($users as $user)
        <td><a href="/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/send" class="btn btn-success" >Approuver</a></td>  @endforeach

Comment: you said that after refreshing page that an emails is sent, this emails are sent without clicking on any button ?

Comment: @Sara i think it's because of the get request, first change the route to `Route::post('/admin/{user}/send','EmailController@send')->nam‌​e('user.send');` then @foreach($users as $user) 
 <td>
  {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => "/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/send"]) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Approuver', ['class'=> 'btn btn-success']) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
 </td> 
@endforeach

Comment: Is the problem dolved ?

Comment: {{$user->id }} bring an error in the 'route' => "/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/send"]) !!}  :   Route [/SurveyApp/public/admin/<?php echo e(2); ?>/send] not defined

Comment: I didn't understand you ? already `<a href="/SurveyApp/public/admin/{{ $user->id }}/send" class="btn btn-success" >Approuver</a>` work already !!

Comment: {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => ['user.send',$user->id]]) !!} it works perfectly now ,thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `SurveyMail` constructor, you've type hinted `$user` as  a `User` object but while instantiating the class you've passed the request data which is an array. Try this

```php
Mail::to($user)->send(new SurveyMail($user));
```

Also, there is no import for `User` object so it assumed that your `User` class is inside `App\Mail`. which it is not. So, import your `App\User` model on top of your class.

```php
use App\User; // <- Add this here

class SurveyMail extends Mailable
```

Also, in your view. you forgot to close the `ul` tag.

```xml
<body style="background: black; color: white">
 <h2>Prise de contact sur mon beau site</h2>
    <p>Réception d'une prise de contact avec les éléments suivants :</p>
    <ul>
      <li><strong>Nom</strong> : {{ $user->name }}</li>
      <li><strong>Email</strong> : {{ $user->email }}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply ,but the error persist even with this modification

Answer (score 1):

You can do following which worked for me. 
From your `SurveyMail` constructor, remove `'User'` before `$user` and make the constructor look like following

```
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

This should fix the error.